# how to find parent product have no category - magento

Tags: php, sql, magento

I have some orphan records of parent product in my magento product catalogue how can i find them with out any extension installation. SQL code will be great.

Comment: This is a question better suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is SQL for this. By the below query you can find orphan(product with no category) product ids.

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku FROM catalog_product_entity AS e LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE l.category_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This shows all records including child producsts. But i only want parent product records.